# Formal word/phrase for "in one big move"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, formality

I'm working with the sentence:

> The company raised over $1 billion, __________ placing it in the top
>   band.

I initially considered "in one fell swoop" but this seems to be a stretch, typically the idiom is used to describe doing multiple things at once. Moreover, it's too casual for my application.

What formal choices might work here? (can change conjugations of my existing words around if necessary)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108997/discussion-on-question-by-arash-howaida-formal-word-phrase-for-in-one-big-move).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try *instantly*: "immediately, without the least delay ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instantly)). Although it doesn't convey that particular sense of the single "fell swoop", it does make it plain that the company raised $1 billion and did not then have the need to do anything else to land at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about how academic it sounds but a suitable word would be *Suddenly*.

```
The company raised over $1 billion, *Suddenly* placing it in the top band.
```

A similar phrase without the swooping would be;

```
The company raised over $1 billion, *all at once* placing it in the top band.
```

Or, combining them;

```
The company raised over $1 billion, *all of a sudden* placing it in the top band.
```

For my tastes I would go with Suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

How about the idiom **in short order**? [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+short+order) offers the following defintions:

> **in short order**: quickly, efficiently, and without any delays.
>
> **in short order**: very quickly.
>
> **in short order**: quickly, without delay
>
> **in short order**: immediately; rapidly (chiefly North American)

Your example:

> The company raised over $1 billion **in short order**, placing it in the top band.

**In short order** has the same feel as *in one big move* and *in one feel swoop*, but perhaps spread out a little more over time, as would be the (relatively prompt) response of the market to an action the company under discussion had taken, e.g., gone public.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to think of an expression that conveys both the idea of size and of a single event. The latter seems more important in the context, given that size is implicit in ‘billion’. I do not really understand the poster’s objection to “one fell swoop”, but a less extravagant phrase expressing the same idea is:

> **at a stroke**

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-a-stroke) explains this as follows (my emphasis):

> “If something happens at a stroke or in one stroke, it happens *suddenly* and *completely* because of *one single action*.”

One reservation I have about this is the slightly incongruent “placing” that follows in the sample sentence. This would seem a little weak in the context, and I would replace it by a verb conveying slightly more action. “Moving” or even just “putting” might be sufficient — “thrusting” or “propelling”, if one wished to be more forceful.

Another point is the positioning of the phrase itself, which more usually is placed at the end of a sentence. So, assuming that “top band” is unambiguous, the following might be my preferred revision:

> The company raised over $1 billion, *propelling* it *into* the top band *at*
>   *a stroke*.

Answer (score 0):

Unmistakenly

The company raised over $1 billion, unmistakenly placing it in the top band.

Comment: This word choice emphasizes the fact that the company is *definitely* in the top band, but does not indicate that it got there suddenly or with a single action, which seems to be what the OP is going for.

Answer (score 0):

The company raised over $1 billion, quick as thought, placing it in the top band.